# how to align custom view items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

Hi I'm using the custom view for `ActionBar`. In that I have followiong problem...please can any one help me

[image]

AS I rotate the screen all items move to left side but I want them align equal.For custom view I'm using Linear Layout..

Following is my code for custom view..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_msg" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewnotification"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_notification1" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewsettings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewsearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:weightSum="4"` for `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"` for each `ImageView`. like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
android:weightSum="4"
android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    ...
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**[EDIT]** also need to set `layout_width="0dp"` for each `ImageView`

Hope it helps cheers :)

Comment: I tried your code but still not happening..and remember I'm setting it on ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

SMR is close. The LinearLayout has to have orientation = "horizontal", and each ImageView has to have the weight (you have already done this), as well as layout_width = "match_parent".